# tow button_click_event crushing together

Tags: android

I have tow on_click event in one activity linked to tow different buttons but what happened is when I press the first or second button the first on_click event is the one who is working!! here is the java code:

```
TextView user;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_activity);
        user=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String msg = i.getStringExtra(("msg"));
        user.setText("welcome"+" "+msg+" choose a category");
    }
    public void science(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,science_first_activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public  void art(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,art_first_activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

and here is the xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_s"
        android:layout_width="258dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="77dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="77dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="76dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="437dp"
        android:onClick="science"
        android:text="science" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_a"
        android:layout_width="258dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="77dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="77dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="76dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="328dp"
        android:onClick="art"
        android:text="art" />
```

no matter what button I click he will keep go to the science activity!

Answer (score 0):

Start activity if view id are equal to avoid that.

```
 public void science(View v){
    
    if(view.getId==R.id.button_s){
            Intent intentS = new Intent(this,science_first_activity.class);
            startActivity(intentS );
        }}


        public  void art(View v)
        {
    if(view.getId==R.id.button_a){
            Intent intentA = new Intent(this,art_first_activity.class);
            startActivity(intentA );
        }}
```